# Separate rows and columns while creating 2d dynamic table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't separate row and column td's as I create a 2d table with jquery..

How do I create 10 rows 10 columns 2d table:

what I have done so far:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        $('.box').append('<td/>' + '</p>');
        for (var j = 1; j <= 10; j++); {
            $('.box').append('<td/>');
        }
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VS37n/

thnx in advance!

Comment: You aren't creating any rows...

Comment: yes! I see now that I create only column why..=?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*You want a table that has 10 columns and 10 rows.*

```
var rows = 10;
var cols = 10;
```

In an HTML table structure, rows come first in the hierarchy, so, create those first:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var rows = 10;
    var cols = 10;
    var box = $('.box');

    for (var r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
        var tr = $('<tr>');
        //Here we will append the columns to the row before appending it to the box.
        box.append(tr);
    }
});
```

The above code only makes 10 rows for us. Now we need to add 10 columns to each row:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var rows = 10;
    var cols = 10;
    var box = $('.box');

    for (var r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
        var tr = $('<tr>');

        for (var c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
            tr.append($('<td><p></p></td>')); //Create the table cell, with a p element as in your example, and append it to the row.
        }

        box.append(tr);
    }
});
```

See this [***FIDDLE***](http://jsfiddle.net/VS37n/5/)

**UPDATE**

I just noticed that the jQuery selector from your post selects the `<div>` element with class `.box`. You want to add these rows and columns, however, to a `<table>` element, which doesn't exist. I'd suggest you add a `<table>` element into your HTML, or, add it with Javascript before adding the rows.

If you can add a `<table>` element inside of your `.box` div, then you would just change the following line:

```
var box = $('.box');
```

to:

```
var box = $('.box table:first');
```

If you can't change the HTML for some reason, then you can dynamically create the table before the rows and columns:

```
var box = $('<table>').appendTo('.box');
```

Comment: I just noticed that `.box` isn't a table. You should make it a table, or, you can put one inside of it, and change `var box = $('.box');` to `var box = $('.box table:first');`

Comment: I got a question: why table:first? instead of table?

Comment: `table:first` would select only the first table inside of the `.box` div. Just incase, more than one table existed for some reason. `.box table` would work just fine as long as you know for sure that only one table would exist.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var tdHtml = "":
  var trHtml = "";
  var tableHtml = "";
  for(var i=1;i<=10;i++)
  {
     tdHtml += "<td></td>";
  }
  for(var j=1;j<=10;j++);
  {
     trHtml += ("<tr>" + tdHtml + "</tr>");
  }
  tableHtml = ("<table>" + trHtml + "</table>");
  $('.box').innerHtml(tableHtml);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You had a `;` after your `for` loop :

```
for (var j = 1; j <= 10; j++); {
    $('.box').append('<td/>');
}
```

Furthermore, you are not adding `<tr>` elements.

See the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VS37n/2/)